Can FastAPI not deserialize a Pydantic model, but still use the model type to construct OpenAPI spec?
Suppose we have:
class Foo(BaseModel):
    very_large_something: list[SomeOtherModel]

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/foos/")
async def create(foo: Foo):
    # something

My JSON request is about 20 MB. The deserialized object is ~ 100 MB. This is too much memory and I am inclined to parse / validate my requests in a stream-based fashion (maybe using https://pypi.org/project/json-stream/). However, I would still be glad if FastAPI could handle generation of the OpenAPI spec based on the Pydantic model. Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:
@app.post("/foos/")
async def create(_unused: Annotated[Foo, DoNotDeserialize], request: Request):
    # something that operates on request and does nothing with _unused


The easiest way would probably be to just add the placeholder type List to the accepted types. FastApi/Pydantic will check the first type see that is a  list and ignore the rest types. In the sametime FastApi documentation will be generated properly but will include two type accepted values.
import typing

class Foo(BaseModel):
    very_large_something: list[SomeOtherModel]

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/foos/")
async def create(foo: typing.Union[typing.List, Foo]):
    # something

If you want to exclude a placeholder type you will probably need to manually exclude it from the OpenApi spec. I found the relevant answer Is there a way to exclude Pydantic models from FastAPI's auto-generated documentation?. Hope it helps.
